# Merge rows in same data frame based on common values

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

Most of the approaches I've come across involve using dplyr to apply a function when combining features, however, I would just like to restructure a single data frame without applying any function to each group.

I have a single data frame that looks like this:

```
gene_name  chr  nb_pos    nb_ref  nb_alt  m_pos    m_ref  m_alt
ACAA1       3   38173733    C      T     38144875     G     T 
ACAA1       3   38144875    G      T     38144876     G     A
```

I would like to combine each row with a common `gene_name` and `chr`, where each gene can have a variable amount of rows, to look like this:

```
gene_name  chr   np_pos1   nb_ref1   nb_alt1  nb_pos2  nb_ref2  nb_alt2  nb_alt2
ACAA1       3   38173733      C         T     38144875    G       T         T
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from the `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install it are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Create a sequence column ('ind') based on the grouping columns ('gene_name', 'chr'), and then use `dcast` specifying the `value.var` columns.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, ind:= 1:.N ,.(gene_name, chr)], 
                gene_name+chr~ind, value.var=names(df1)[3:8])
#  gene_name chr 1_nb_pos 2_nb_pos 1_nb_ref 2_nb_ref 1_nb_alt 2_nb_alt  1_m_pos
#1:   ACAA1   3 38173733 38144875        C        G     TRUE     TRUE 38144875
#   2_m_pos 1_m_ref 2_m_ref 1_m_alt 2_m_alt
#1: 38144876       G       G       T       A
```

Or using `reshape` from `base R` after we create the sequence column using `ave`.

```
 df2 <- transform(df1, ind=ave(seq_along(gene_name),
           gene_name, chr, FUN=seq_along))
  reshape(df2, idvar=c('gene_name', 'chr'), timevar='ind',
     direction='wide')
 # gene_name chr nb_pos.1 nb_ref.1 nb_alt.1  m_pos.1 m_ref.1 m_alt.1 nb_pos.2
 #1     ACAA1   3 38173733        C     TRUE 38144875       G       T 38144875
 #  nb_ref.2 nb_alt.2  m_pos.2 m_ref.2 m_alt.2
 #1        G     TRUE 38144876       G       A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene_name = c("ACAA1", "ACAA1"), chr = c(3L, 3L
), nb_pos = c(38173733L, 38144875L), nb_ref = c("C", "G"), 
nb_alt =   c(TRUE, 
TRUE), m_pos = 38144875:38144876, m_ref = c("G", "G"), m_alt = c("T", 
"A")), .Names = c("gene_name", "chr", "nb_pos", "nb_ref", "nb_alt", 
"m_pos", "m_ref", "m_alt"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much; clearly outlined explanation, link to instructions for installing required packages and options for base package!